# WCF netTCP EntityFramework WindowsAuthenticated SQL

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, nettcpbinding

I am using WCF netTCP and passing Windows Identity. But EntityFramework is not allowing WindowsAuthenticated SQL connections. SQL login works fine, but it always has. I have verified that the Thread.CurrentPrincipal does contain the correct identity (domain\networkid). But the EntityFramework attempt is rejecting the machine name (domain\machineid). (this is a safe corporate network)

From the WCF server, this returns the correct domain\networked:

```
var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
var identityName = principal.Identity.Name;
```

From the SAME server, the SAME method, this does not work:

```
var myEntities = new Declared_EF5_Entities()
```

The error tells me that domain\machineid$ is not a valid user in that SQL database. Note: the app.config contains the connection string and specifies `IntegratedSecurity=true`.

All of the code works without any tricks fine when self-hosted.

This did not help:

```
using (var impcontext = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
{
var myEntities = new Declared_EF5_Entities()
```

Comment: Hello Mark ;-) - are you able to put a breakpoint on the Entity Framework DB Context and see what the connection string is? It is most likely EF is picking up its connection string from the config file and using it. you need to most likely modify it to match the identity being passed into it.

Comment: Possible Double Hop problem?  http://www.aspnet-answers.com/microsoft/ASP-NET-Security/30269990/impersonation-and-double-hop.aspx

Comment: My EF is DB-first and I'm using "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" (followed by EF Designer from Database), not the "EF 6.x DbContext Generator". In any event, the App.Config connection string is absolutely being used. Here is the full string:
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient; provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer;initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: Mike - I think you are right. But the article does not help in this case. I'm using netTcp on a corporate LAN with full AD backing. The configuration is programmatic, not declarative. using this: var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport)

Comment: I ran into the issue not too long ago, and the answer was turning on kerberos in the server and tying it into Active Directory as described here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1043330-359-1.aspx  For our environment, we have an audit log for all changes in the application with the user id, so we just took the path of least resistance with a Sqlserver login for the application.  Hopefully it's a step toward solving this.